# Python: trying to create a two variable context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python so my guess I'm doing something "syntactically" incorrect. I'm trying to iterate over a grid using `row` and `col` as a coordinate system. This my code so far:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

# this is the behavior I want
for row in range(10):
    for col in range(10):
        print("row: {}, col: {}".format(row, col))

@contextmanager
def grid_iter():
    for row in range(10):
        for col in range(10):
            yield row, col

# this is my attempt at a context manager so I can reuse this.
with grid_iter() as row, col:
    print("row: {}, col: {}".format(row, col))
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
row: 0, col: 0
row: 0, col: 1
row: 0, col: 2
....
row: 9, col: 7
row: 9, col: 8
row: 9, col: 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grid_iterator.py", line 17, in <module>
    with grid_iter() as row, col:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: Context managers have absolutely nothing to do with iteration, so replacing a `for` with a `with` makes no sense. No clue what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Aran-Fey see this Ruby example (I'm coming from ruby and `yield` is something use a lot in the same context): https://medium.com/chaos-elevators/ruby-an-example-of-each-with-index-1357bce4e2c4

Comment: I should elaborate: `each_with_index` yields two variables which you can pass to the "block" or basically what you `yield`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to just do:

```py
def grid_iter():
    for row in range(10):
        for col in range(10):
            yield row, col

for row, col in grid_iter():
    print("row: {}, col: {}".format(row, col))
```

the usage of `yield` itself makes `grid_iter` return a generator (you can check this by running `print(type(grid_iter()))` and then you use it like a normal for-in loop

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm a ruby guy so I'm used to doing `..do |row,col|; ...  end;` Is it possible to pass to variables like I was trying to do or is that not allowed in Python?

Comment: @triplethreat78 I've never written Ruby and I'm not familiar with this pipe construct, so I don't really know :(

Comment: If you're curious, here's an example: https://medium.com/chaos-elevators/ruby-an-example-of-each-with-index-1357bce4e2c4 Ok so it looks like it works from within the file but when I try to `import gird_iter` (my file name is grid_iter.py) it gives me this error: `in __init__
    for row, col in grid_iter():
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: oh so looks like `lst.each ... do` in Ruby is almost identical to `for ... in ...` in Python, except for the scope of the iteration variable(s)

Comment: about the `import` problem: this is namespaced, try `for row, col in grid_iter.grid_iter()`, or change the import to `from grid_iter import grid_iter`